# how to replace non ascii character with their respective character in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ascii, non-ascii-characters, iconv, ruby-1.8.7

i used iconv to replace the character:

```
<%= Iconv.iconv("ascii//translit", "utf-8", "ENDÜœSTRIYEL").to_s %>
```

it displays, 
   END?oeSTRIYEL

whereas in irb it shows like this:

```
irb(main):006:0> Iconv.iconv('ascii//translit', 'utf-8', 'ENDÜœSTRIYEL').to_s
=> "ENDUoeSTRIYEL"
```

how to get the full translation of the nonascii characters as in irb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The iconv facility of glibc has a transliteration that depends on the locale:

```
$ echo "ENDÜœSTRIYEL" | LC_ALL=C iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
END?oeSTRIYEL
$ echo "ENDÜœSTRIYEL" | LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
ENDUEoeSTRIYEL
$ echo "ENDÜœSTRIYEL" | LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
ENDUoeSTRIYEL
```

As you can see, three different results for three different locales.

If you are hosting a server that is meant to handle input from users in different countries, you have two options:

- Use a single locale for all users, and hope it's good enough for all.
- Switch the locale temporarily for each conversion (using `uselocale`, not `setlocale`). However, I don't know whether `uselocale` is available in Ruby.

Comment: but im using ruby 1.8.7.. i couldn't able to use like the above mentioned